# Outlook add-ins : Event Based activation & Runtimes

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developping an Add-in on outlook to automatically set signatures when a new message is being composed (on web and desktop)

I am trying to use the Event based activation as in this sample :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-officeaddins/outlook-add-in-set-signature/

Sadly, even the example doesn't seem to work. Is my version of Outlook not supporting the Event-Based activation and the signature set ?

Environment setup : Microsoft Outlook 2016 (16.0.5182.1000) Exchange 2016 (build version 15.1.2375.7) on-premise

Comment: Which Mailbox requirement Set are you using? Please refer to this document to check the supported versions- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch
[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Comment: I'm currently capped to 1.5 with my company's outlook setup

Comment: Event based activations are supported from Requirement set 1.10 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

The [setSignatureAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-body-setsignatureasync-member(1)) method which adds or replaces the signature of the item body is defined in the Mailbox 1.10 requirement set (as well as `OnNewMessageCompose`). Read more about that in the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#how-to-preview) article.

Note, event-based add-ins in Outlook on Windows require Windows 10 version 1809 (build 17763.2989) or later to run.